# How to Create a Route for Tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, tags, acts-as-taggable-on, railscasts

I'm using the gem `acts-as-taggable-on` to create tags for goals and valuations (aka values).

To start I directed the route to this: `get 'tags/:tag', to: 'valuations#index', as: :tag`

But now I want to add tagging to goals as well. How do I change the route so that when a User clicks on a tag (ex: "america") it will list out all the User's "america" tags in one index that combines valuations **AND** goals.

The route would look like this: URL/tags/tagID

This is a beginners question that I couldn't find on the web.

I followed this **Tutorial**:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging?view=asciicast

**Github:** https://github.com/RallyWithGalli/ruletoday

Thanks for your support =]

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you want to visit a route like `/tags/rails` and go to a page that shows either valuations or goals that have a tag rails?

(Or, do you want to go to a `goals#show` page and have all of its tags show up)

You may want both. In the first case, I think what you want is nested routes.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :tags do 
  get 'valuations', to: 'valuations#index'
  get 'goals', to: 'goals#index'
end
```

This way, you could go to '/tags/rails/goals' and get to the goals index, which would filter by tag if :tag is present.

Comment: Thanks Evan I updated the question. I think your on the right track but when I use your code and remove: `get 'tags/:tag', to: 'valuations#index', as: :tag`, I get this error: `uninitialized constant TagsController.`